# pip download specificying platform any - results in no matching distributions

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I am trying to download python dependencies for a case where a system doesn't have network access. If I perform the downloads on my mac without specifying the platform and only-binary everything works fine. However, if I specify --only-binary:all: and --platform any, it gives me an error that it can't find distributions (like pandas). Do I need to run this on a windows machine for it to work? What am I doing wrong?

I have been referencing the pip download info: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_download/

```
py -m pip download ^
   --only-binary=:all: ^
   --platform any ^
   --python-version 3 ^
   --implementation py ^
   --abi none ^
   SomePackage
```

Works:

`python -m pip download -d ./packages pandas -r requirements.txt`

Doesn't work:

`python -m pip download --only-binary=:all: --platform any  --python-version 3 -d ./packages pandas -r requirements.txt`

Error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas
```